# Uncaught TypeError: TheContract.at is not a function

Tags: web3js, abi, interfaces

just trying my first steps in ethereum and web3. So i found this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hcTPjpPvas8

But it raise an error:
index.html:85 Uncaught TypeError: TheContract.at is not a function
at index.html:85

Here is my code:

```
var TheContract = new web3.eth.Contract([
    {
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "_fName",
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "name": "_age",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "setInstructor",
        "outputs": [],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "getInstructor",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    }
    ]);
    
    //var AdressContract =  TheContract.at("0x5fd16b1Fac5835F744061ED2B92a83864aB75688");

    var theContractAt = TheContract.at('0x5fd16b1Fac5835F744061ED2B92a83864aB75688');
    console.log(theContractAt);
```

I guess, because the upper case in contract is also new to the new version of web3, that the .at() function changed... but I just cant find how they changed.

Comment: `at` is relevant on web3.js v0.x, or if you're using Truffle (which wraps web3.js functions regardless of web3.js version). You're probably on web3.js v1.x.

Comment: Just change `]);` to `], '0x5fd16b1Fac5835F744061ED2B92a83864aB75688');`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change ]); to ], '0x5fd16b1Fac5835F744061ED2B92a83864aB75688');. – goodvibration

Works thanks